# Google Mlkit PointF3D Class equivalent for Swift for Pose Detection

Tags: swift, google-mlkit

I am currently working on Pose classification - https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/pose-detection/classifying-poses and using the sample Android project to create the classifier for iOS using Swift.

In this process, I need to convert the PoseEmebedding file. There is a function that [imports PointF3D from Google MLKit vision common API in Android sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/18437dc2a9bd7b97d4abe392b20e7828fb606362/android/vision-quickstart/app/src/main/java/com/google/mlkit/vision/demo/java/posedetector/classification/PoseEmbedding.java#L42) but this is not present in the iOS version of MLKit for pose detection.

Is there any reference to Android's [PointF3D Class](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/common/PointF3D) for Swift?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. ML Kit's Pose Detection API in swift returns a 3D point in [Vision3DPoint](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/reference/swift/mlkitvision/api/reference/Classes/Vision3DPoint). You are right. Only the Java version of the Android sample app contains code for pose classification. You will need port it into swift.

Comment: Yes, I have checked Vision3DPoint for swift as well. I thought that this was Swift's version of PointF3D. But Vision3DPoint doesn't contain the methods which are present in PointF3D. Since this is part of the Google Mlkit library, do we need to create these wrappers on our own in Swift?

Comment: Which methods in PointF3D are not provided by Vision3DPoint?

Comment: All the methods like from, getX etc

Comment: You can get the x-coordinate via this: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/reference/swift/mlkitvision/api/reference/Classes/VisionPoint.html#/c:objc(cs)MLKVisionPoint(py)x